# How to Merge/Combine two PHPBB3 accounts

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb3

PHPBB3 is the version I am using.

Hello, I have a problem where a user might want to merge accounts on my site, I know how to merge their accounts on my store but not the forum which is PHPBB. How can you merge two accounts on PHPBB. I know i could just go to the database and alter values myself while also deleting one of the accounts but I don't what tables exactly i would even need to alter.

So how can you merge/combine two PHPBB3 accounts?

As in user1 has 10 posts. User2 has 10 and I want one user with 20.

Comment: As in user1 has 10 posts. User2 has 10 and you want a single user wirh 20 posts ?

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the official phpBB STK (Support Tool Kit) to merge users - https://www.phpbb.com/support/stk/

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE phpbb_topics SET `topic_poster` = 2 WHERE `topic_poster` = 1;
UPDATE phpbb_topics SET `topic_first_poster_name` = 'user2' WHERE `topic_first_poster_name` = 'user1';
UPDATE phpbb_posts SET `poster_id` = 2 WHERE `poster_id` = 1;
```

Change the usernames and ids accordingly
Make sure you run a back up BEFORE running these commands.

This handles posts only and you will likely need to resync in admin panel after

Pms are harder and profile info is near impossible.